# What does "her arms tighten about his neck in gratitude" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> her arms tighten about his neck in gratitude

The sentence comes from Collins dictionary. What is my confusion is that why use "tighten about his neck" rather than "tighten his neck".

Besides, I also want to know what the meaning of 'in gratitude' is. Is HE has a gratitude for her or Is SHE has a gratitude for him?

Comment: I see no closure reason. There is a source, and a clear point of misunderstanding. It is evident that the OP has used a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

1: It is her arms that tighten, not his neck. They are around his neck, which she hugs tighter.
2: It is she who is tightening her arms, so it is she who is expressing gratitude to him.